# MySQL SQL Performance need some improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have worked my way around many challenges with MySQL, and i think right now i am able to build everything that i need, to get something to work. But now, for a pretty huge SQL statement that returns a lot of data, i need to work on MySQL performance for the first time.

I was hoping someone here could help me find out why the following statement is so incredibly slow. It takes over 3 minutes to collect 740 results out of different tables. The biggest table beeing the "reports" table, consisting of somewhere over 20.000 entries at the moment.

I can also educate myself if someone could just point me in the right direction. I don't even know where to search for answers for my current problem.

Okay, so here is the statement that i am talking about. Maybe, if someone has enough experience with SQL performance, something just right away jumps at them. I would be happy for any kind of feedback. I'll elaborate on the statement right after the code itself:

```
SELECT 
    R_ID,
    R_From,
    R_To,
    SUM(UR_TotalTime) AS UR_TotalTime,
    R_Reported,
    U_ID,
    U_Lastname,
    U_Firstname,
    C_ID,
    C_Lastname,
    C_Firstname,
    R_Breaks,
    MAX(CR_BID) AS CR_BID,
    R_Type,
    R_Distance,
    R_AdditionalDistance,
    R_Activities,
    R_Description,
    R_Signature,
    CT_SigReq,
    MAX(I_LastIntegration) AS I_LastIntegration
FROM
    reports
        LEFT JOIN
    userreports ON R_ID = UR_RID
        LEFT JOIN
    users ON R_UID = U_ID
        LEFT JOIN
    customers ON R_CID = C_ID
        LEFT JOIN
    customerterms ON CT_CID = R_CID
        LEFT JOIN
    integration ON R_UID = I_UID
        LEFT JOIN
    customerreports ON R_ID = CR_RID
WHERE
    (CAST(R_From AS DATE) BETWEEN CT_From AND CT_To
        OR R_CID = 0)
        AND ((R_From BETWEEN '2021-02-01 00.00.00' AND '2021-02-28 23.59.59')
        OR (R_To BETWEEN '2021-02-01 00.00.00' AND '2021-02-28 23.59.59')
        OR (R_From <= '2021-02-01 00.00.00'
        AND R_To >= '2021-02-28 23.59.59'))
GROUP BY R_ID
ORDER BY R_From ASC
```

So what i have here is the following:
**reports** (R_*) - This is the main table that is queried. I need some of it's data, but it's also the filter, since i only need results between specific timestamps.

```
CREATE TABLE `reports`  (
  `R_ID` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `R_Type` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `R_UID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `R_CID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `R_From` datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `R_To` datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `R_Traveltime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `R_Breaks` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `R_PayoutFlextime` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `R_Distance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `R_AdditionalDistance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `R_Activities` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `R_Description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `R_Signature` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `R_SignatureDate` datetime(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Reported` datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `R_Status` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'New',
  `R_EditedBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_EditedDateTime` datetime(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`R_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

**userreports** (UR_*) - Delivers some data that is calculated from the sourcedata in reports

```
CREATE TABLE `userreports`  (
  `UR_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UR_RID` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `UR_UID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `UR_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `UR_From` time(0) NOT NULL,
  `UR_To` time(0) NOT NULL,
  `UR_ReportedTime` decimal(20, 5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_ReportedTravel` decimal(20, 5) NOT NULL,
  `UR_ReportedBreaks` decimal(20, 5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_TotalPercentageSurcharge` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_TotalTime` decimal(20, 5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_PercentageSurchargeTypes` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_Distance` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_AdditionalDistance` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UR_TravelCompensation` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UR_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

**customerreports** (CR_*) - Same as userreports, but with calculated data from the customers perspective

```
CREATE TABLE `customerreports`  (
  `CR_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CR_RID` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `CR_CID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `CR_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `CR_From` time(0) NOT NULL,
  `CR_To` time(0) NOT NULL,
  `CR_ReportedTime` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_ReportedBreaks` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_Hourly` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_Salary` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_TotalPercentageSurcharge` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_TotalFixedSurcharge` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_TotalTime` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_TotalSalary` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_FixedSurchargeTypes` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_PercentageSurchargeTypes` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_Distance` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_AdditionalDistance` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_TravelCompensation` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CR_BID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CR_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

**users** (U_*) - Obviously delivers Data to the user that created the report, e.g. name,...

```
CREATE TABLE `users`  (
  `U_ID` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `U_PW` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_PWInitial` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `U_FailedAttempts` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `U_Email` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Title` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `U_Firstname` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Lastname` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_ETC` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Street` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Housenumber` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Code` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_City` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Phone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Mobile` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `U_Sex` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Maritalstatus` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Severelydisabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `U_Severelydisabledspecify` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `U_Citizenship` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Education` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Vocationaltraining` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_CLID` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `U_CLSpecify` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_IBAN` varchar(27) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_BIC` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_INID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `U_Insurancenumber` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Insurancetype` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Taxidentificationnumber` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Confession` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_Entry` date NOT NULL,
  `U_TEntry` date NOT NULL,
  `U_Exit` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
  `U_Hourscarryover` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `U_TotalHolidayCarryover` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `U_UsedHolidayCarryover` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `U_SIN` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `U_RVBDone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `U_ClosedMonth` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
  `U_DeleteDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`U_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

**customers** (C_*) - Same as users, but for the data of the customer that the user worked on

```
CREATE TABLE `customers`  (
  `C_ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `C_MID` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `C_Email` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `C_Title` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `C_Firstname` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Lastname` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `C_ETC` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Street` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Housenumber` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Code` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_City` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Phone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Mobile` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_IBAN` varchar(27) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_BIC` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Insurancenumber` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_INID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Insurancetype` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Sex` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Contact1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `C_Contact2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `C_ContactChoice` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `C_DeleteDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_DeactivationDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_CreationDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_DeceasedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`C_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

**integration** (I_*) - Provides data on whether or not the report is already integrated (and can no longer be changed)

```
CREATE TABLE `integration`  (
  `I_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `I_UID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `I_LastIntegration` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
  `I_SumFlextime` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `I_OldHolidays` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`I_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

**customerterms** (CT_*) - In this case only provides if the specified customer needs to sign the report

```
CREATE TABLE `customerterms`  (
  `CT_ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CT_CID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `CT_From` date NOT NULL,
  `CT_To` date NOT NULL,
  `CT_Hourly` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `CT_FixedTravelCompensation` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `CT_PerKMCompensationBase` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `CT_PerKMCompensationAdditional` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `CT_MaxTravelCompensationReport` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CT_MaxTravelCompensationMonthly` decimal(20, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CT_FixedSaturdaySurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `CT_PercentageSaturdaySurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.00,
  `CT_FixedSundaySurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `CT_PercentageSundaySurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.00,
  `CT_FixedHolidaySurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `CT_PercentageHolidaySurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.00,
  `CT_SigReq` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `CT_NighttimeFrom` time(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `CT_NighttimeTo` time(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `CT_FixedNighttimeSurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `CT_PercentageNighttimeSurcharge` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.00,
  `CT_StackingSurcharge` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CT_MinimumTime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `CT_TimeIncrement` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CT_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

The server is running MySQL 5.7, has 4 processors at 4,6Ghz, and 16GB of RAM available.

Since this is a hobby project, that i am supporting small care-businesses with, to allow them easier management of their daily tasks, i can change everything here. Code, Database Layout, you name it. As long as the poor people in the office don't have to wait for 5 minutes, just to sometimes even only get a timeout...

I'll add the result of EXPLAIN as image, since i can't get it to look good
otherwise...

[image: RESULT of EXPLAIN]

```
+─────+──────────────+──────────────────+─────────────+─────────+──────────────────────+──────────+──────────+──────────────────────────+───────+───────────+─────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
| id  | select_type  | table            | partitions  | type    | possible_keys        | key      | key_len  | ref                      | rows  | filtered  | Extra                                               |
+─────+──────────────+──────────────────+─────────────+─────────+──────────────────────+──────────+──────────+──────────────────────────+───────+───────────+─────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
| 1   | SIMPLE       | reports          | NULL        | ALL     | PRIMARY,R_From,R_To  | NULL     | NULL     | NULL                     | 22249 | 29.76     | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort        |
| 1   | SIMPLE       | userreports      | NULL        | ALL     | NULL                 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL                     | 21359 | 100.00    | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  |
| 1   | SIMPLE       | users            | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY  | 4        | dbs671769.reports.R_UID  | 1     | 100.00    | NULL                                                |
| 1   | SIMPLE       | customers        | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY  | 4        | dbs671769.reports.R_CID  | 1     | 100.00    | NULL                                                |
| 1   | SIMPLE       | customerterms    | NULL        | ALL     | NULL                 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL                     | 1429  | 100.00    | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  |
| 1   | SIMPLE       | integration      | NULL        | ALL     | NULL                 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL                     | 1134  | 100.00    | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  |
| 1   | SIMPLE       | customerreports  | NULL        | ALL     | NULL                 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL                     | 9078  | 100.00    | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  |
+─────+──────────────+──────────────────+─────────────+─────────+──────────────────────+──────────+──────────+──────────────────────────+───────+───────────+─────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
```

Is there any way to consolidate all this data faster, but as reliable?

Thanks a lot in advance, for any help or idea on this.

Comment: Read about indexes and explain.

Comment: see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions and add missing information

Comment: Thanks, i have added all of the missing inforation i was able to provide!

Comment: @jarlh What would i have to put that index on? Since the joins all work with the ID-Fields, that are in fact the Primary-Keys, they should already work as indexes, right?

Comment: Please include the result of the explain as well!

Comment: @Shadow: I did so, thanks! I have already tested adding indexes for R_From and R_To, because of their use in the WHERE clause, but i feel this doesn't work well with BETWEEN statements...

Comment: The BETWEEN will use the indexes just fine.

Comment: I believe that the "BETWEEN CT_From AND CT_To" is going to require every row to get checked and not be able to use indexes.

Comment: @MarcelLehmann Congratulations on getting the indexes added to get your 3 minutes to 3 seconds.  Life gets better with experience.  Remember any JOIN with leftside = rightside NEEDS index for the leftside and rightside matching columns for high performance and the columns should have the same data types and lengths to avoid 'dumbing down' the matching requirement (and slowing the process significantly).  You may now Upvote Comments and likely Accept Answers.  Great job providing data for us to analyze your 'SLOW' performing query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by adding an index for each of the foreign keys used in your query -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `userreports`
    ADD INDEX `FK_UR_RID` (`UR_RID`);

ALTER TABLE `customerterms`
    ADD INDEX `FK_CT_CID` (`CT_CID`);

ALTER TABLE `integration`
    ADD INDEX `FK_I_UID` (`I_UID`);

ALTER TABLE `customerreports`
    ADD INDEX `FK_CR_RID` (`CR_RID`);
```

Please add these indices and then add the updated EXPLAIN output plus the result of the following query to your question.

```sql
-- this just retrieves some basic stats about size of each table used in your query
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE, VERSION, TABLE_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LENGTH, DATA_LENGTH, INDEX_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbs671769'
AND TABLE_NAME IN('customerreports', 'customers', 'customerterms', 'integration', 'reports', 'userreports', 'users');
```

Comment: Oh my god, why didn't this occur to me.... I just thought "The primary keys are indexed anyways, what else should i be able to index?". And i literally only thought about the FROM and TO fields...
But indexing the foreign keys did the job! It brought down the time for a regular reports from 3+ Minutes to 3 seconds!
I'll still add the requested data later, gotta go though some meetings before though...

Comment: Please upvote as well as accepting answers. FK indexing is so important, even for relatively small joins. What sort of performance improvement did you get? As Rick James points out there are lots of other things to tackle which will dramatically improve performance. Changing all the text columns to appropriately sized varchars and using appropriate integer types would be a good place to continue.

Comment: Sadly i am not allowed to upvote... i tried to, but i need 15 reputation first, and it seems i am too new here...

Comment: Sorry, I should have known that. Don't forget to update with the additional data. I am sure we can help get it much faster than that.

Comment: @MarcelLehmann - Take the "tutorial"; it's a quick way to get 100 more reputation points.

Comment: @MarcelLehmann - Apparently you did not declare any FKs; they would have implicitly created an `INDEXes`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    WHERE  (CAST(R_From AS DATE) BETWEEN CT_From AND CT_To
              OR  R_CID = 0
           )
```

`OR` is sluggish.  Is there some way to get rid of `R_CID = 0`?  If not, we can talk about `UNION`.

Rewrite the rest thus:

```
           R_From >= CT_From  AND  R_From < CT_To + INTERVAL 1 DAY


      AND  ((R_From BETWEEN '2021-02-01 00.00.00'
                        AND '2021-02-28 23.59.59')
          OR  (R_To BETWEEN '2021-02-01 00.00.00'
                        AND '2021-02-28 23.59.59')
          OR  (R_From    <= '2021-02-01 00.00.00'
               AND  R_To >= '2021-02-28 23.59.59')
           )
```

Is `R_From` guaranteed to be `< R_To`?  If so, would this simplification (OR-removal) do the same

```
   AND R_From  < '2021-03-01'
   AND R_To   >= '2021-02-01'
```

This requires two passes over the intermediate results:

```
    GROUP BY  R_ID
    ORDER BY  R_From ASC
```

This requires one pass, while usually giving the same results, maybe even better results:

```
    GROUP BY  R_From, R_ID
    ORDER BY  R_From, R_ID
```

(Pet peeve:  Don't prefix column names with the table name (or 'R_'); Do use aliases for all columns when JOINing:  `SELECT R.ID ... FROM reports AS R  JOIN ...` )

Another Answer has mentioned some `INDEXes`; that may give you a lot of speed-up.  After some of my suggestions, there may be more index tips.

`TEXT` columns have some overhead; many of the cases you list could be done with something smaller, like `VARCHAR(100)`.  For example, currently, the longest "city" name in the world has only 91 chars:  "Poselok Uchebnogo Khozyaystva Srednego Professionalno-Tekhnicheskoye Uchilishche Nomer Odin"

You seem to be running an old version of MySQL?  Else you might have been dinged for the `GROUP BY`; cf "only_full_group_by".